# repeater in a javascript tags

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im following a tutorial [at this site](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Google-Maps-V3-with-Multiple-Markers-Database-Example.aspx)
The repeater is inside the javascript tags and it is not identified and has errors can someone assist me how does this work? because i thought a repeater is an asp control how does that work in javascript tags?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
        {
        "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
        "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
        "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
        "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
    }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];
</script>
```

Comment: generally it looks fine,asp control can be put to render javascript,the server controls are read first then they get rendered, then sent to the client, so the client will be seeing the output of the repeater which is javascript, even if you want it to print CSS you can or anything that will be read on the client.

what errors are you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine like that there is no problems with it.